# M/M/1 queueing theory system

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, queueing-theory

[image]

Could someone verify if my calculated parameters are right?

λ = arrival rate = 0.8

Ws = average time spent in the system = 18/4 = 4.5

Ls = average number of customers in the system = 18/10 = 1.8

The little's law is not satisfied and I am not sure where I went wrong.

Update...

Number of customers = 4

Total time spent in the system = 18

Comment: Little's law applies to the long-term average of customers in a stationary system - not to the transient behavior we are interested in here. As far as determining how many customers are in the system at time $t$, make a table with the arrival and service times of each customer. This will let you determine when each customer departs the system, and hence how many customers are in the system at any given time.

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you. I have done both table and plot and I got total service time of 11 so μ = 11/4 but still can not apply little's law .

Comment: Little's law does not apply to this type of problem...